# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-b^k)$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $b\in(0,1)$ and define $a_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-b^k)$. Is the infinite series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$$
convergent or not? I tried the standard convergence criteria but they don't seem to work.

Comment: First determine whether $a_n \to0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the hint. It seems that $a_n$ does not converge to 0, which would obviously settle my question. But can you prove that $a_n$ does not converge to 0?

Comment: Estimate from below the series $\sum_{k=1}^n \log(1-b^k)$.